# Is electron capture the exchange of a virtual $W$-boson?

Tags: radiation, virtual-particles, weak-interaction, exchange-interaction, electron-capture

Betaplus: an upquark emits a $W^+$-boson which turns it into a downquark and then *decays* into a positron and electron neutrino.

Electron capture: an upquark emits a $W^+$-boson which is *absorbed* by a shell-electron, turning both the upquark into a down and the electron into an electron neutrino. Or the other way around. Right?

So are you wrong in saying betaplus is the *emission* of a $W^+$ and EC the *exchange* of a $W^+$?

Comment: Both are off mass shell so they are virtual.( on shell W has a mass over 80 GeV, way beyond the energy/momenta available to beta decays or electron captures

Comment: @annav well... Yes. I see now that I'd have to agree. But then how come they are almost always depicted with a slight incline in Feynman diagrams? That indicates they exist for a brief moment of time, no?

Comment: @Faalkar No, internal lines of Feynman diagrams are always virtual particles.

Comment: @PM2Ring oh, thank you good sir. You just took me on a train of very useful information. So why is it inclined in some cases....?